# Apollo based server giving error code - BAD_USER_INPUT

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm using Vendure headless e-commerce and trying to run a GraphQL mutation according to the specs - but I'm running into an error I cannot seem to decipher.

The error I'm getting is:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "extensions": {
            "code": "BAD_USER_INPUT"
        },
        "locations": [{
            "line": 1,
            "column": 28
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is in turn pointing to the `$input` variable.

```
query: "mutation AddPaymentToOrder($input: PaymentInput!) {\n  ... etc ...
```

Usually when I've gotten this error code it means I've made a mistake in the mutation, but in those cases I get a clear message what is wrong. In this mutation I get nothing.

The Vendure docs on this mutation are quite simple: https://www.vendure.io/docs/graphql-api/shop/mutations/#addpaymenttoorder

The mutation I've written is quite simple as well for now:

```
export const AddPaymentToOrderQuery = gql`
mutation AddPaymentToOrder($input: PaymentInput!) {
    addPaymentToOrder(input: $input) {
        ... on Order {
            id
        }
    }
}
`;
```

The data I send looks like this:

```
type Variables = {
    input: {
        method: string;
    }
};
```

Does anyone understand this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a misunderstanding - a missing input data element `metadata` that I had forgotten.

Input should look like:

```
type Variables = {
    input: {
        method: string;
        metadata: Object;
    }
};
```